# Find and replace string based on column and value dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, replace

Hi I have a datagridVew with 5 columns. The user will select any cell and pass the value `Str1` and `Str2` for find and replace. But, I want to restrict find & replace to only one column to which the selected cell belongs

How can I do that ?

Comment: The question is not clear that what exactly you want.Do you want to restrict find & replace to only one column to which the selected cell belongs?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. May you please describe what you are exactly trying to do? :)